# jQgrid not loading the custom userData on loadComplete

Tags: json, ajax, jqgrid

I'm trying to get some custo datam sent from the server stored in the json with the table data. The JSON that I'm sending is this one

```
{"total":1,"page":1,"records":1,"userdata":{"aaa":"bbb"},"rows":[{"id":0,"cell":["ampolla","1"]}]}
```

and I'm trying to get this userdata in the loadComplete event with this

```
loadComplete: function() {          
    console.log(jQuery("#gridDataGraphic").getGridParam('userData'));
},
```

According to other posts I think that I'm building properly the json with "userdata" and getting after with "userData", so I don't know where is my problem.

The entire jQgrid definition is this one (just in case someone needed):

```
$("#${gridDataGraphic}").jqGrid({
    url: gridUrl,
    postData: gridPostData,
    datatype: "json",
    height: "auto",
    autoencode: true,
    shrinkToFit: true,                   
    autowidth: true,        
    multiselect:false,
    forceFit:true,              
    loadui: '',
    loadtext: '',
    altRows: true,
    altclass: 'ui-priority-altRow',
    colNames:["<bean:message key='label.category'/>",
              "<bean:message key='label.value'/>"
              ],
    colModel:[
            {name:'${dataGraphicColumnCategory}', index:'${dataGraphicColumnCategory}', resizable:false, editable:false, search:false, sortable:true},
            {name:'${dataGraphicColumnValue}', index:'${dataGraphicColumnValue}', resizable:false, editable:false, search:false, sortable:true}
            ],
    rowNum: rowNums,
    gridview: true,
    mtype: "POST",                  
    pager: jQuery('#${pagerDataGraphic}'),
    sortname: "${lastOrderName}",
    sortorder: "${lastSortOrder}",
    page: "${ReportGenerationForm.currentPage}",
    sidx: "${param.sidx}",
    sord: "${param.sord}",
    viewrecords: true,
    onCellSelect: function(rowid,iCol,cellcontent) {},      
    pginput:true,
    loadError: function (xhr, status, error){
        showErrorDialog("<bean:message key='system.error.body'/>: " + error);
    },
    recordpos:"right",
    pagerpos:"center",
    loadComplete: function() {
        console.log(jQuery("#gridDataGraphic").getGridParam('userData'));
    },
    gridComplete: function() {},
    onSortCol: function (index, columnIndex, sortOrder) {
        $("#${gridDataGraphic}").trigger('reloadGrid');                                             
    }
});
```

Now the grid is perfectly loaded and shows the row; but console log is returning **undefined** :(

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you call a grid which does not exist (maybe) replace:

```
loadComplete: function() {
    console.log(jQuery("#gridDataGraphic").getGridParam('userData'));
},
```

with

```
loadComplete: function() {
    console.log(jQuery("#${gridDataGraphic}").getGridParam('userData'));
},
```

Comment: Thanks! Now is working :)

Comment: Thanks. Glad to help.